# Docker not executing with adequate permissions to unzip file - how to elevate Docker permissions?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

We have some Python scripts that leverage Docker to:
1. Take a zip file and extracts it (failing)
2. Parses the content and presents it in a webpage via Apache (working, yet not fully because of step 1 failing)

Step 1 is failing because permissions are not allowing for `unzip` to work. I can manually unzip the file, but the webpage does not display properly. Contents of the Python script are intellectual property of the company I work for, so I cannot post any of them here.

So far I have tried:
- Running all Python scripts as root (no change)
- `sudo setfacl -m user:myUserName:rw /var/run/docker.sock`
...but this returns: `setfacl: /var/run/docker.sock: Operation not permitted`

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 via Windows Subsytem for Linux (Windows 10).

Comment: The docker daemon can't be run in WSL now. You've to run docker daemon in Windows or in a VM.

Comment: Perhaps it's WSL Ubuntu docker then. I can run CMD/PS -> Bash -> `docker run hello-world` and it returns the `Hello from Docker!` message, confirming Docker is working normally.